# Are there any rules concerning the variable symbols in first-order languages?

Tags: formal-languages

I have read that one part of alphabet in first-order languages is an infinite collection of variables. Are there any rules about what the symbols of these variables should look like? One can often read that they're assigned lowercase letters from near the end of the Latin alphabet, often with numerical subscripts, e.g. $x_{353}$. However, what about variables like $a^{\rightarrow}$, a symbol of a vector, or Greek letters often used for angles in geometry? Variables in real world mathematics often use symbols very different from "lowercase letters from near the end of the Latin alphabet". So are there any rules about what should variable symbols look like, besides "different from symbols already defined as not being variables"?

Comment: For a very detailed discusssion see George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1: Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA5) (2003), **Ch.I.1. First Order Languages**, page 5-on, and specifically on *variables*, page 9-on.

Comment: For a very "abstract" mathematical definition of *first-order language*, see J.Donald Monk, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bq7bBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA162) (1976), page 162.

Comment: I have read the first few pages of Tourlakis' book and if I understand correctly, only $v_1$,$v_2$ etc. are variables and if we use another symbols like $x$ or $z$, then technically we aren't working in the formal language of first-order logic. Is this correct?

Comment: See page 7; "In practice – whether we are using logic as a tool or as an object of study – we agree to be sloppy with notation and use, generically, $x, y, z, u, v, w$ with or without subscripts or primes as names of object variables. Conventions such as this one are essentially agreements – effected in the metatheory – on how to be sloppy and get away with it. They are offered in the interest of user-friendliness." We have already discussed in a previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742699/do-we-have-to-write-down-definitional-abbreviations-when-writing-the-alphabet-fo) ...

Comment: ... the issue of the "trade-off" between fully formal specifications (algorithmically executable by a machine) and human-readibility.

Comment: Why not save ourselves the trouble and define _all_ symbols which aren't defined as something else as variables, so that whenever we want a new symbol for a variable, we already have it? The post you linked doesn't explain what I'm asking for, since I know that in the real world there is nothing wrong with being "sloppy" in the way Tourlakis described. I'm asking why exactly there is a need to specify variables only as $v_1,v_2...$ and not do the thing I said in the beginning? This way we could still do formal proofs with better human readability and without being sloppy.

Comment: @user1321213 That approach seems atractive, but turns out to be an obstacle if one later wants to *extend* the language. Say, we have the Peano axioms and say that everything except $0$, $S$, $=$, $\land$, $\neg$, $\to$, $\forall$, $($, $)$ shall be considered a variable. But then we want to extend the language and define $\lor$, $\leftrightarrow$, $\exists$ in terms of other logical symbols, or define a binary operation $+$ recursively in terms of $S$, or a binary operation $\cdot$ recursively in terms of $+$. This may become awkward when these symbols are already variables per the above rule

Comment: Good enough. Is there anything wrong with extending the set of variables.by definitions? I don't see any obstacles but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Note that real-life math formulas are *not* what we learn to call well-formed-formulas of first-order languages. This follows already from the two-dimensional arrangement in things like
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k=(1+x)^n $$
That being said, in order to really *specify* a formal language *strictly*, you need to *define* your alphabet, including that countable set of variables, for example as one specific letter $x$ indexed by a natural number (note that this would make things like $x_{1728}$ a *single* symbol!); or as one of several *specified* letters, possibly followed by a finite sequence of apostrophes (so a symbol *sequence* such as $x''''$ would represent a variable syntactically).